# 403 Forbidden | WordPress | Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx, plesk

Intenté actualizar WordPress manualmente en uno de mis sitios. 
Para evitar problemas cloné el sitio en un servidor de pruebas y procedí con la actualización, todo excelente.

Cuando probé con el servidor de producción no puedo proceder con la actualización.

Si intento acceder a: https://example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php aparece el siguiente error "403 Forbidden - Nginx".

Pasos que he realizado:

- Colocar los permisos correctamente
- Verificar la configuración de Nginx, Apache y Php entre los servidores de producción y prueba.
- Mirar el log

Resultados del log `/logs/proxy_error_log` (***únicamente un trozo***):

```
2019/01/15 15:31:18 [error] 34346#0: *88652 access forbidden by rule, client: 188.XXX3.175.168, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/pomo/pictur.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/16 20:53:19 [error] 34346#0: *137331 access forbidden by rule, client: XXX.129.113.142, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/pomo/idomen5.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/16 20:53:20 [error] 34346#0: *137333 access forbidden by rule, client: XXX.199.100.XXX, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/pomo/sliverone.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/16 20:53:38 [error] 34346#0: *137335 access forbidden by rule, client: XXX.129.113.142, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/pomo/sqlbasa1.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/16 20:54:22 [error] 34346#0: *137375 access forbidden by rule, client: XXX.129.113.142, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/pomo/monolit.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/16 20:54:33 [error] 34346#0: *137382 access forbidden by rule, client: XXX.199.100.XXX, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/pomo/mon0lit.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/16 20:56:13 [error] 34346#0: *137413 access forbidden by rule, client: XXX.199.100.XXX, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/pomo/sliver.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/16 20:56:XXX [error] 34346#0: *137418 access forbidden by rule, client: XXX.199.100.XXX, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/pomo/sqlbasa.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/17 09:34:16 [error] 2931#0: *151697 access forbidden by rule, client: 75.99.13.124, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2018/12/minify.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/XXX 16:41:12 [error] XX408#0: *317578 access forbidden by rule, client: 139.59.29.XXX9, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/wp-tomar.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/22 XXX:51:16 [error] XX408#0: *361382 access forbidden by rule, client: 75.99.13.123, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/SimplePie/Canonical.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/01/26 19:31:42 [error] 48850#0: *5XX492 access forbidden by rule, client: 193.106.XX.98, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/images/hon2our.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2019/01/28 18:08:42 [error] 19018#0: *616XXX2 access forbidden by rule, client: 193.106.XX.98, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/js/tinymce/global.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2019/01/31 XXX:58:11 [error] 39094#0: *749880 access forbidden by rule, client: 193.106.XX.98, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2019/02/02 06:47:01 [error] 56731#0: *829281 access forbidden by rule, client: 193.106.XX.98, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2018/08/seo_script.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2019/02/11 07:26:27 [error] 33168#0: *1254155 access forbidden by rule, client: 193.106.XX.98, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/indes.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2019/02/13 15:25:29 [error] XXX38#0: *753 access forbidden by rule, client: XXX.238.164.172, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2019/02/anis.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/02/13 15:XX:23 [error] XXX38#0: *XXX6 access forbidden by rule, client: XXX.238.164.172, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/pomo/jss.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/02/17 04:25:31 [error] 26015#0: *128152 access forbidden by rule, client: 193.106.XX.98, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/css/login_wall.php?login=cmd HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2019/02/18 01:08:11 [error] 46833#0: *165343 access forbidden by rule, client: 193.106.XX.98, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-content/uploads/2018/11/seo_script.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"
2019/02/XXX 04:44:42 [error] 49736#0: *333674 access forbidden by rule, client: 5.XXX.143.224, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce-help.php HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "example.com"
2019/02/22 12:51:28 [error] 41734#0: *399013 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 88.XXX.255.137, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://82.XXX.31.116:7081/favicon.ico", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
2019/02/25 09:32:12 [error] 39222#0: *5XXX95 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 88.XXX.255.137, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://82.XXX.31.116:7081/favicon.ico", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
2019/02/25 09:32:13 [error] 39222#0: *5XXX95 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 88.XXX.255.137, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://82.XXX.31.116:7081/favicon.ico", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
2019/02/25 09:32:42 [error] 40168#0: *513608 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 88.XXX.255.137, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://82.XXX.31.116:7081/favicon.ico", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
2019/02/25 09:32:43 [error] 40168#0: *513608 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 88.XXX.255.137, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://82.XXX.31.116:7081/favicon.ico", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php"
example@vendo:~/logs$ cat proxy_error_log
```

Normalmente Plesk se encarga de configurar absolutamente todo, por lo que no sería necesario tocar manualmente la configuración de nginx, apache o php. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Imagino que el servidor de origen era un apache y el de destino es un nginx, ¿es así o el nginx hace de frontal al apache? PD: ¿Podrías compartir los apartados [`location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) del servidor nginx? Es importante, sobre todo, ver dónde está configurada la regla [`deny`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#deny) que te impide acceder a esa ruta. PD2: ¿Podrías también decirnos si el resto de la web te da el mismo error?

Comment: En "Apache & nginx Settings" está activa la opción "Proxy mode - Nginx proxies requests to Apache. Turn off to stop using Apache" (Supongo que te refieres a eso). También me gustaría añadir que está activa en los 2 servidores.

Comment: He probado crear un fichero test.php con un simple "echo" y lo que colocado en /wp-admin/ y desde el navegador puedo acceder perfectamente.

Comment: El problema podría residir en alguna configuración para un archivo PHP específico, por eso necesito saber qué reglas `deny`/`allow` tienes y bajo qué directivas `location`. Si quieres descartar que sea el apache el que genera el error por algún `.htaccess` y nginx lo reproduce puedes probar a desactivar el modo proxy durante un rato y ver si persiste el error. Pero por lo pronto lo más importante es revisar la configuración del nginx.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus respuestas Oscar, lo aprecio mucho. Te comento, acabo de desactivar el modo proxy y el error persiste, por otro lado, no tengo privilegios para acceder al conf de nginx, en unas horas intentaré subirlo.

Comment: Si persiste entonces descartamos que sea un error de apache propagado al nginx. Claramente con esa prueba es problema de configuración de permisos en nginx. En cuanto puedas comprobar los archivos de configuración para ver dónde está la regla `deny` que te está impidiendo el acceso podrás solucionarlo.

Comment: Acabo de notar que el servidor de pruebas en el apartado "PHP Settings" únicamente tiene la opción "run PHP as FPM application", no obstante, en el otro servidor me da 3 opciones: FPM application serverd by nginx, FPM application serverd by Apache y FastCGI application serverd by Apache

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90194/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-carlos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que la [extensión *wp-toolkit* de Plesk](https://www.plesk.com/wp-toolkit/) ha sido la responsable de todo este problema, por lo que recomiendo **NO REALIZAR** una actualización manual de WordPress en caso de tener instalada la extensión mencionada anteriormente en tu servidor.

En [este enlace](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003057873-The-WordPress-admin-dashboard-is-not-accessible-when-the-WordPress-Toolkit-maintenance-mode-is-enabled), se explica la forma correcta de actualizar WordPress con dicha extensión:

- [Crear un clon](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/website-management/wordpress-toolkit.73391/#o78077) del sitio.
- Poner en modo mantenimiento el de producción en **Plesk > Domains > (dominio) > WordPress > Maintenance mode**.
- Aplicar las actualizaciones y cambios necesarios en el clon.
- [Realizar una sincronización](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/website-management/wordpress-toolkit.73391/#o78160).
- Quitar el modo mantenimiento.

Con la ayuda de [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia) hemos podido dar solución después de varias horas.

Comment: Fue un placer poder ser de ayuda. He mejorado la estructura de tu respuesta agregando algunos enlaces de interés y separando la descripción de los pasos en puntos para que pueda ser de mejor ayuda a otros usuarios que vengan aquí en busca de una solución a este problema.